# Как подключить внешнюю базу данных SQLite в Android?

Tags: android, sql, база-данных, sqlite

Мне нужно получить значения, содержащиеся в колонках заранее созданной базы данных.

Пробовал двумя способами:

- создавал наследника SQLiteOpenHelper,
- пытался использовать библиотеку android-sqlite-asset-helper.

Пытаюсь выполнить данные через курсор:

```
Cursor cursor = myDataBase.query("таблица",new String[]{
        "колонка1",
        "колонка2",
        "колонка3",
        "колонка4",
        "колонка5",
        "колонка6",
        "колонка7",
        "колонка8",
        "колонка9"}, null, null, null, null, null, null);

String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("колонка1");
```

В обоих случаях выдается ошибка

> :no such table "имя моей таблицы".

Таблица есть - проверял через DB Browser,через него и создавал базу.

Я так понимаю, он просто не видит эту базу данных. Кидаю базу в assets (меня смутило, что не было этой папки в Android Studio 1.5.1 - создал с помощью New/ Assets Folder).

Использую [этот код](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605555/android-accessing-assets-folder-sqlite-database-file-with-sqlite-extension/5949629#5949629). Тестирую на Android 4.1

Comment: Возможно разрешения не хватает на чтение с диска в манифесте.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, про разрешения совсем забыл

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Как делал я.

1. Положил БД в папку assets
2. У меня есть класс для работы с БД

   import java.io.FileOutputStream;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.InputStream;
   import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class ExternalDbOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
//Путь к папке с базами на устройстве
public static String DB_PATH;
//Имя файла с базой
public static String DB_NAME;
public SQLiteDatabase database;
public final Context context;
//private boolean flagdel = true;

public SQLiteDatabase getDb() {
    return database;
}

public ExternalDbOpenHelper(Context context, String databaseName) {
    super(context, databaseName, null, 1);
    this.context = context;
    //Составим полный путь к базам для нашего приложения
    DB_PATH = context.getDatabasePath(databaseName).getAbsolutePath();
    DB_NAME = databaseName;
    openDataBase();
}

/**Создаст базу, если она не создана и откроет ее*/
public void createDataBase() {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if (!dbExist) {
        this.getReadableDatabase();//Создает и/или открывает базу данных
        try {copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database!");
        }
    }
}

/**Проверка существования базы данных*/
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDb = null;
    String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    try {
        checkDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {}
    //Андроид не любит утечки ресурсов, все должно закрываться
    if (checkDb != null) checkDb.close();
    return checkDb != null;
}

/**метод проверки наличия в БД таблицы*/
public boolean checkTableInDB(String nameTable){
    boolean result = false;
    Cursor cur = database.query("sqlite_master", new String[]{"name"}, "type=? AND name=?", new String[]{"table",nameTable}, null, null, null);
    cur.moveToLast();
    if(cur.getCount()>0) result = true;
    cur.close();        
    return result;
}

/**метод проверки наличия поля в таблице*/
public boolean checkFieldInTable(String nameTable, String nameField){
    boolean result = false;
    try{
        Cursor cur = database.rawQuery("PRAGMA table_info('"+nameTable+"')", null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        while(!cur.isAfterLast()) {
            String name = "";
            try{name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name"));
            }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){}
            if(name.equals(nameField)){
                result = true;
                break;
            }
            cur.moveToNext();
        }
        cur.close();
        cur = null;
    }catch(SQLException e){}
    return result;
}

/**Метод копирования базы*/
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    // Открываем поток для чтения из уже созданной нами БД источник в assets
    InputStream externalDbStream = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    // Путь к уже созданной пустой базе в андроиде
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    // Теперь создадим поток для записи в эту БД побайтно
    OutputStream localDbStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    // Собственно, копирование
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = externalDbStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        localDbStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    // Мы будем хорошими мальчиками (девочками) и закроем потоки
    localDbStream.close();
    externalDbStream.close();
}

/** Метод получения всех данных из таблицы*/
public Cursor getAllData(String dbTable) {
    return database.query(dbTable, null, null, null, null, null, null);
}

/** Метод получения данных из таблицы по условию*/
public Cursor getDataByWhere(String table, String[] columns, String where, String[] where_args) {
    return database.query(table, columns, where, where_args, null, null, null);
}

/**Метод открытия БД*/
public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    if (database == null) {
        createDataBase();
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }
    return database;
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if (database != null) {
        database.close();
    }
    super.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {}
```

}

3. Получаю данные в любом нужном мне месте кода. Ниже метод получения данных. Смысл в том, что если БД с определенной версией не найдена, то она будет скопирована в папку с установленным приложением и далее получена на нее ссылка с дальнейшим использованием. Очень удобно. Советую.

   ```
   private void getDataFromDB(){
     ExternalDbOpenHelper dbOpenHelper = new ExternalDbOpenHelper(context, DB_NAME);
     SQLiteDatabase db = dbOpenHelper.getDb();

     String orderby = MeData.getOrderBy();
     String table = (!mode.equals(MODE_PREV))?MeData.getTable():MeData.getTable_prev();
     String columns[] = MeData.getColumns();

     Cursor cur = null;
     try{cur = db.query(table, columns, where, where_args, null, null, orderby);
     }catch(Exception e){
         if(cur != null) cur.close(); cur= null;
         if(db != null) db.close(); db = null;
         if(dbOpenHelper != null) dbOpenHelper.close(); dbOpenHelper = null;
         return;
     }
     cur.moveToFirst();
     while(!cur.isAfterLast()) {
       try{
           int ND = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("ND"));
           int NM = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("NM"));
           int NY = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("NY"));
       } catch(Exception e) {}
       cur.moveToNext();
     }
     if(cur != null) cur.close(); cur= null;
     if(db != null) db.close(); db = null;
     if(dbOpenHelper != null) dbOpenHelper.close(); dbOpenHelper = null;
   ```

   }

P.S. Не могу толком вставить код... прошу прощения, разберетесь...

Comment: а как тогда с помощью данной конструкции извлечь какую-нибудь строку из столбца?Я понял, что нужно создать в какой-нибудь активности экземпляр ExternalDbOpenHelper,а что дальше

Comment: Да как угодно. Это же sql.

Comment: @DenisIvanov, ну например:
`public static String getData(Context context, int id, String field){
 ExternalDbOpenHelper oh = new ExternalDbOpenHelper(context, DB_NAME);
 SQLiteDatabase db = oh.openDataBase();
 Cursor cur = null;
 String strSQL = String.format("SELECT %s FROM %s WHERE id=%s",field,"mtTable",String.valueOf(id));
 cur = db.rawQuery(strSQL, null);
 cur.moveToFirst();
 String result = "";
 while(!cur.isAfterLast()) {
  result = cur.getString(0);
  cur.moveToNext();
 }
 if(cur != null){cur.close();cur = null;}
 if(db != null){db.close(); db = null;}
 oh = null;
 return result;
}
`

Comment: На устройствах с несколькими пользователями такое `/data//data//%s//databases//"` не прокатит

Comment: @katso, возможно. Я пока не сталкивался с такой проблемой. Можете подсказать ее решение?

Comment: @dubok79, http://pastebin.com/CB9QQnqn

Comment: @katso, спасибо, я поправил. Где то я уже это у себя переправлял. Видно в этом классе забыл.