# Как правильно хранить куски текста в одном файле?

Tags: java, android

Есть файл с простой разметкой (как .ini).
Разметка например такая:

```
[A1]
1=Текст A1-№1
2=Текст A1-№2

..........

[A2]
1=Текст A2-№1
2=Текст A2-№2
```

Как правильно и в какой папке хранить такие текстовые файлы, из которых я собираюсь формировать текст для вывода в TextView?
Как формировать запрос на поиск нужного текста с такой разметкой?
Может в JAVA есть аналог ini разметки?

Comment: в Java есть классы для работы с ini файлами. Чем не устраивает?

Comment: Да, например "ini4j". Попробую использовать его. Хотя вопрос больше касается оптимальности использования ini для хранения текстов.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Для хранения произвольных файлов  в структуре приложения Android выделены папки */assets* и */res/raw*. Доступ к этим ресурсам возможен только на чтение.

Различия кроются в способе доступа и организации хранения этих файлов.

Ресурсы в папке */assets* могут иметь произвольную структуру подкаталогов, имен файлов и доступ к ним организуется через класс `AssetManager`, отдельные файлы не имеют идентификаторов в классе `R.java`, доступ к ним организуется напрямую по имени файла. [Подробнее про ресурсы /assets](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/assets.php)

Ресурсы в папке */res/raw* не могут иметь структуры подкаталогов, доступ к ним осуществляется по идентификатору, заданному в `R.java`, через синтаксис `R.raw.*`. Так же такие файлы несколько ограничены типом - разрешено хранить аудио, видео, html-страницы, текстовые файлы и тп. [Подробнее о каталоге *res/raw/*](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/resources.php#raw)

Кроме того, существует каталог */res/xml/*, в котором можно хранить произвольные XML файлы (файлы структурированой информации, аналогичной той, которая представлена в вашем вопросе). Ресурсы так же имеют идентификаторы в `R.java` и обращаются к ним через `R.xml.*`. [Подробнее](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/resources.php#xml).

Перечисленные выше места хранения используются только для хранения статической информации - ее можно читать, но нельзя изменить или (до-)переписать.
Если вам требуется доступ и на запись, то в таком случае файлы хранятся вне структуры приложения, на внешнем носителе. По умолчанию система Android выделяет для каждого приложения область на внешнем диске (по пути *`/data/data/<package_name>`*), куда программа может [записывать и считывать данные](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal), но вы так же можете указать произвольное место работы (каталог), [например, на SD-карте](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal).

Отличие в хранении в выделенной для приложения области в том, что эта область никаким образом недоступна другим приложениям (за исключением приложений с root-правами), так же при удалении приложения эта область удаляется вместе с ним. При хранении на SD-карте, доступ к данным может получить кто угодно и они не уничтожаются вместе с приложением при его деинсталяции.

Альтернативным способом хранения может быть запись значений в таблицу SQLite. Этот способ оправдан при необходимости делать произвольные выборки, а так же связывать различные данные (содержимое таблиц) между собой, так как организация работы с БД требует больших трудозатрат и дополнительных знаний в области СУБД - при простом хранении набора данных выгоднее и "дешевле" хранить его в структурированном файле.
Тем не менее, вы так же можете подготовить БД и разместить ее в каталоге */assets*, а затем скопировать на устройство ([один из примеров](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/488845/177345)). При этом база данных с которой могут работать классы Android может располагаться только в специальной выделенной области приложения по пути `*/data/data/<package_name>/database/*`. При размещении в любом другом месте (например на SD-карте), Android не сможет с ней работать (либо вам придется написать свои классы работы с БД, которые смогут это делать).
Размер самого файла БД несущественно больше размера хранимых в нем данных - этим в свете экономии места на диске можно пренебречь.

Аналоги INI файлов со встроенными в Android API инструментами для обработки - файлы форматов JSON и XML.

При довольно распространенном паттерне, когда требуется какой то заполненный данными файл, который потом необходимо модифицировать, поступают следующим образом: файл помещают в каталог */assets*, при старте приложения [его копируют оттуда в область выделенную приложению или на SD-карту](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4447477) и затем уже работают с скопированным файлом. Файл в */assets* при этом остается в первоначальном состоянии и фактически является балластом, но ничего не поделаешь.
Так же есть вариант создание файла динамически из кода, в некоторых случаях это позволяет существенно сократить объем приложения, то же относится и к заполнению таблиц SQLite.

Comment: Куски текста мне придется менять, поэтому хранить придется на SD карте. Тогда встает вопрос, куда мне на этапе разработки разместить текстовые файлы, чтобы после создания дистрибутива, они в него вошли. И после установки на устройство, распаковались на SD карту. Нашел еще вариант хранения в SQLite, но опять же как указать чтобы база хранилась на SD карте и каков моежт быть е размер.

Comment: @kaaa дополнил ответ