# Отличие папок drawable/raw и assets. Плюсы и минусы загрузки изображений из drawable и assets и raw

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-drawable

В заголовке уместил весь вопрос. Я кое что о них знаю, но мои знания поверхностны и может не верны. Хотел бы хотя бы ключевые различия узнать.   могу ли я получить разные raw в зависимости от плотности. Например drawable-xhdpi/raw/qwerty.png ? Есть вообще разница между asset и drawable/raw..

Comment: [Этот вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/515204/177345) не совсем по вашей теме, но о отличиях /assets и raw/ там достаточно написано.