# Запись в файл что находится в папке raw

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Как я могу записать информацию в файл находящийся в папке raw?

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(R.raw.textfile, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Данный метод не работает. Подсвечивает красным R.raw.textfile. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все внутренние ресурсы приложения (/raw, /assets, /drawable, /xml и тд.) только для чтения, запись в них невозможна.

[Подробнее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/515204/177345) о назначении папок ресурсов и способах хранить информацию в Android