# Хранение данных в андроид офлайн

Tags: android, база-данных, sqlite, хранение-данных

Есть необходимость хранить фиксированные данные на андройде, их достаточно много, но обновляться они не будут. Приложение полностью офлайновое. Как правильно записать данные в apk заранее?

Comment: какого рода данные?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как в тегах БД, то речь видимо идет о способах ее заполнения перед началом работы программы.

Проще всего уже [готовую БД поместить в assets/](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/523666/177345) и потом скопировать в каталог приложения, опять же проще всего это сделать с помощью готовой небольшой библиотеки (в ответе по ссылке).

Можно подумать, что копирование БД - затратный по размеру итогово apk-файла вариант, но это не так, так как аналогичный объем данных так или иначе будет присутствовать в приложении в виде статичного одноразового груза, будь то файл JSON, XML или ресурсы в прямо в коде. Затраты в общем размере базы на структуру этой базы несоизмеримо меньше размера самих хранимых в ней данных, но вы можете сэкономить какое то количество байт, пожертвовав временем начального старта, если параметр размера критичен.

Остальные варианты хуже в том плане, что поэлементный разбор и занесение в БД займет существенно больше времени, чем прямое копирование одного файла готовой БД. Так же сформировать и оттестировать базу на компьютере гораздо проще, чем на телефоне.

Больше [вариантов хранения данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/515204/177345) в android-приложении оффлайн.