# Относительный путь к файлу в андроид проекте

Tags: android, path, properties

В проект добавлен файл res/data/list.properties.
Мне нужно загрузить из него данные. Пытался так:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("data/list.properties"));
```

Файл не найден. Как правильно указать путь?

Comment: нашел такой пример. Resources r = activity.getResources();
            InputStream is = r.openRawResource(R.raw.test)

Comment: как получить объект Resourses, если доступ идет из виджета, не имеющего активити?

Comment: Resources - объект класса Context, а не Activity/ Все виджеты имеют контекст, к нему и обращайтесь (`view.getContext().getResources()`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы не можете создавать произвольные каталоги с файлами в системном каталоге *res/* приложения.

Для решения вашей проблемы поместите ваш файл, например, [в каталог */assets*](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/assets.php) (находится на одном уровне с каталогом *res/* и затем прочитайте свой файл оттуда:

```
AssetManager assetManager = getResources().getAssets();

try {
    InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("list.properties");
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(inputStream);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Подробнее [о каталогах для хранения данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/515204/177345) в Android