# Хранение большого объема данных приложения

Tags: android, база-данных

Есть приложение "Книга рецептов". К каждому блюду пишется рецепт как приготовить. Я подразумеваю, что нужна БД, но Firebase вряд ли подойдет.

Вопрос : Что нужно использовать для хранения большого количества данных, в данном случае рецептов к каждому блюду?

Comment: Так вы на внешнем сервере хотите хранить?

Comment: @КириллМалышев Я вообще хочу узнать как лучше и где хранить большое количество данных. Т.к. блюд будет много, а значит рецептов тоже много.

Comment: Есть принципиальная разница хранить все рецепты локально на устройстве пользователя. Тогда может увеличиться размер приложения, зато не нужен Интернет. Или использовать какое-то внешнее хранилище. Тогда загружать контент может тогда, когда он нужен, но пользователю нужен Интернет, а вам - где-то хранить это всё.

Comment: @КириллМалышев тогда лучше наверно использовать внешнее хранилище. На данных момент, я использую Firebase, с помощью него я отображаю список продуктов в RecyclerView, которые может выбрать пользователь. Firebase можно и для хранения рецептов тоже использовать или есть что-то получше ?

Comment: Я не использовал Firebase, но, наверно, он может быть неплохим решением, если нужно просто внешнее хранилище. Альтернативой является аренда виртуального сервера. Это если вы хотите делать какой-то более серьёзный сервис.

Comment: @КириллМалышев та нет, мне еще рановато арендовать сервер, т.к. я только начал знакомиться с android-ом :)

Comment: Вопрос в том, что вы хотите в итоге: научиться пользоваться БД или создать удобное приложение? Во втором случае (особенно если список рецептов изначально конечен) лучше "зашить" всю инфу при компиляции: через `json`, `txt` в `assets` или `string-array`. Вряд ли размер вырастет значительно, а вот отзывов на GP: "Не работает без интернета! 1*" вы не получите.

Comment: @Jarvis_J можете подробней мне объяснить,что я должен просмотреть, ибо я еще не работал с json, txt в assets или string-array. Для меня это "первый свет" . Хочу научиться работать с БД и в тоже время создать удобное приложение.

Comment: в рамках комментария к вашему вопросу тяжело объяснить подробнее)) погуглите (как парсить json/txt android). `string-array` максимально простой вариант, который предполагает, что вы создадите текстовые массивы в `xml` в `res/values` и заполните их вручную. Если появится новый конкретный вопрос - вы всегда его можете здесь задать ;)

Comment: Локальные БД: ORM - room, realm; хардкор - чистый SQLite. Удаленные Firebase, Realm (платный функционал) @Jarvis_J для сборника рецептов хранение в json или массиве стрингов, по моему мнению, так себе решение, особенно, если планируется какая то интерактивность, поиск, фильтрация. Здесь уместнее БД во много.

Comment: немного информации [о локальном хранении данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/515204/177345) в андроид