# Сохранение файлов программы (Java, Android)

Tags: java, android, файлы, файловая-система

Столкнулся с проблемой... В одном из пакетов программы есть несколько используемых "некомпилируемых" файлов.
Каким образом я могу их заранее "впихнуть" в *APK-файл*, чтобы они устанавливались вместе с программой, например, в папку **data**, или просто в корне для дальнейшего использования...

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Заранее спасибо)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/515204/177345

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша система сборки по умолчанию наверняка должна включать ресурсы...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если папки с такой иконкой у вас нет, ее можно добавить, нажав правой кнопкой на желаемой директории и выбрать вот это из меню:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: @Dev0ps помогло? Всегда пожалуйста

Comment: Можно ещё вопросик: почему IDE автоматически не создает пакет программы в папке Android/data?

Comment: @Dev0ps, IDE не может и не должна ничего создавать на устройстве - этим уже будет заниматься операционная система. Конкретно папка в `Android/data` будет создана при первом обращении к ней через методы контекста `getExteral...`

Comment: Понял, спасибо)