# Создание первоначальных данных в БД приложения

Tags: android, база-данных

Нужно каким то образом при первом запуске создавать БД с рецептами блюд, чтобы затем их просто подгружать из БД и все. Как это можно сделать? Или может запихнуть БД в сам apk?

Comment: Можно и программно заполнить, можно и готовую использовать. Если данных много, то второй вариант попроще, так как в спец.программе на компе это все удобнее делать, чем кодом. И на тот и на другой вопрос уже отвечали

Comment: @pavlofff, а какой программой на компе можно заполнить БД ?) и как потом в коде обращаться к этой готовой БД? И как готовую БД запихнуть в АПК?))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно поместить готовую БД в APK. Это предпочтительнее, потому что на компьютере подготоваить БД проще и есть возможность нормально протестировать запросы, перед тем, как использовать для выборки курсоров.

Для заполнения и тестиривания БД я пользовался [*SQLite Expert Personal Edition*](http://www.sqliteexpert.com/)  - бесплатный и довольно мощный менеджер баз SQLite, выполняющий практически все функции, которые есть в платных аналогах. Можно там и запросы протестировать, получив наглядный результат, а не курсор, в который не посмотришь.

Готовая база данных ложится в каталог */assets* приложения простым копированием файла в эту папку проекта, но работать оттуда она не может, так как эта папка для статических (неизменяемых) ресурсов и должна быть скопирована в раздел на устройстве, выделенный для вашего приложения (обычно `/data//data/<package_name>/databases/`), где вашему приложению разрешена запись и прочие операции работы с файлами.
Сделать это можно с помощью собственного кода ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/488797/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bd%d1%8e%d1%8e-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-sqlite-%d0%b2-android/488845#488845)) или готовой библиотеки [*android-sqlite-asset-helper*](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper), что предпочтительнее (тогда база ложится в каталог *assets/database/* приложения)

После копирования пользоваться этой БД нужно точно так же, как если бы она была создана прямо на устройстве. Фактическая разница только в том, что в первом случае БД туда копируется, во втором изначально создается там.

PS: Если размер начальной БД (то, что вы помещаете в каталог *assets/*) более одного мегабайта, то расширение для БД должно быть указано, как для несжимаемого типа данных (*.png, *.mp3), а не *.bd или там *.sqlite - это связано с тем, что каталог *assets/* подвергается сжатию и существует ограничение на размер файлов для этой операции в 1 Мб.

Можно так же и заполнить БД прямо на устройстве. Для этого придется создать какую то структуру с данными, вроде XML или JSON файла, распарсив который вы будете заполнять свою БД запись за записью. Это дольше на первом старте приложения, чем копирование готовой БД и не так удобно для тестирования, но несколько меньше по итоговому размеру APK и не имеет никаких ограничений по начальному размеру БД.