# Не работает запрос query в SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

Рассмотрел этот пример https://metanit.com/java/android/14.3.php
[image: Изображение]

Создал БД с отметкой 0 и 1. 
Столбцы:

`static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";`

`static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";`

`static final String COLUMN_CHECK = "check";`

Появились проблемы:

1) Пишу:

```
 userCursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE, null);
```

Все работает.

Пишу:

```
String query = "SELECT " + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ID + ", " + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME  +  " FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE;
userCursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
```

Все работает.

Пишу:

```
String query = "SELECT " + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ID + ", " + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME + ", " + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_CHECK  +  " FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE;
userCursor = db.rawQuery(query, null); (т.е. все столбцы как и select * from)
```

Не работает.

Ошибка:

> SQLiteLog: (1) near "check": syntax error

Могу узнать значения из check имя_курсора.getInt(2) (select*from)

2) Обновление данных в таблице.

```
cv.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME, String.valueOf("Привет"));
//cv.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_CHECK, String.valueOf(2));
db.update(DatabaseHelper.TABLE, cv, DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ID 
+"="+String.valueOf(2), null);
```

При `DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_CHECK` - ошибка, при `DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME` - значение меняется.

3) Как сделать, чтобы при update менялась сама БД, а не ее копия. Т.е. я удалил БД из assets, но приложение работает. Сама БД не изменяется, а копия ее меняется.

Comment: check - зарезервированное слово. https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/table-constraint.html

Comment: вы не можете записывать в папки ресурсов приложения (как res/assets) и соответственно менять данные в БД, эти папки доступны только для чтения, [создается копия БД](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/523666/177345) в папке пользователя и дальнейшая работа идет с ней, оригинал в /assets лежит "мертвым грузом" - это неизбежное зло или о какой копии идет речь?

Comment: @pavlofff переделал код под SQLiteAssetHelper https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper. Как написать метод update (для обновления одного значения в поле), там есть про upgrade. И как сделать, чтобы при изменении также изменялась бд в assets/databases, а не ее копия. И последний вопрос: как сделать, чтобы при каждом новом запуске приложения бд открывалась заново (т.е. с новыми значениями), а не использовалась ее копия. Пытался сам искать информацию, но безрезультатно.

Comment: повторю еще раз: каталог /assets доступен ТОЛЬКО ДЛЯ ЧТЕНИЯ. Вы НИКАК не можете записывать в оригинал базы данных. При первом запуске БД копируется в каталог пользователя и дальнейшая работа идет с копией. Для записи в БД есть методы insert() и update() класса SQLiteDatabase. Все о работе с БД написано в [официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html). При каждом новом запуске будет открываться копия БД с сохраненными значениями. Копирование из /assets производится ОДИН РАЗ, при первом старте приложения и все.