# libgdx sqlite на android, .db не переносится в Android

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite, libgdx

Android Studio. На пк чтение с бд работает успешно, в Android БД пустая. 
Саму бд храню в каталоге assets, там же где все картинки. Все картинки без проблем в android используются

```
dbHandler = DatabaseHandlerFactory.getNewDatabaseHandler(DATABASE_NAME, DATABASE_VERSION, DATABASE_CREATE, null);
dbHandler.setupDatabase();
dbHandler.openOrCreateDatabase();
```

dbHandler не находит .db файл в телефоне и создает новую пустую бд, как мне перенести бд в android, чтобы я мог её считать?

**Код AndroidLauncher на основе ответа *Chaynik*** (рабочий)

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {
    Context mycontext;
    private static String DB_NAME = "database.db";
    private String DB_PATH;
    private void copydatabase() throws IOException {
        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myinput = mycontext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outfilename = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myoutput = new FileOutputStream(mycontext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME));

        // transfer byte to inputfile to outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myinput.read(buffer))>0) {
            myoutput.write(buffer,0,length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myoutput.flush();
        myoutput.close();
        myinput.close();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        mycontext = getContext();
        DB_PATH = getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+"/databases/";
        try {
            copydatabase();
        } catch(IOException e) {};
        initialize(new ReactionTeacher(1), config);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы копируете уже готовую БД в каталог assest?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/523666/177345

Comment: класс `AndroidAplication` библиотеки libgdx имеет метод `getContext()` - используйте его для получения контекста

Comment: [Обновить БД](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738623/copy-database-from-assets-folder-in-unrooted-device/29058717#29058717) посмотрите здесь

Comment: @McDaggen Извините что поздно ответил, да, готовая в assets

Comment: @pavlofff предлагаете создать объект класса AndroidAplication? AndroidApplication androidApplication = new AndroidApplication();
  androidApplication.getAssets();

Comment: @RuslMag не понял предложения, по вашей ссылке предлагается принудительно скопировать бд из assets в андроид, как это предложил Chaynik, но у меня возникла проблема с Context

Comment: Видимо с ООП вообще и Java в частности вы пока на ВЫ? Ваш класс **наследуется** от класса `AndroidApplication` и метод `getContext()` доступен в наследниках этого класса. пишите в своем классе-наследнике: `getContext().getAssets()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не сможете работать с базой из каталога ресурсов вашего приложения - вам ее с начала нужно скопировать в каталог вашего приложения на карту памяти. Алгоритм простой.

- Вы проверяете наличие файла базы в каталоге вашего приложения
- Если файл не найден, скопировать из assets.

Вот код взятый с подобного вопроса на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5949629/2667883)

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private Context mycontext;

    //private String DB_PATH = mycontext.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+"/databases/";
    private static String DB_NAME = "(datbasename).sqlite";//the extension may be .sqlite or .db
    public SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    /*private String DB_PATH = "/data/data/"
                        + mycontext.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
                        + "/databases/";*/

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) throws IOException {
        super(context,DB_NAME,null,1);
        this.mycontext=context;
        boolean dbexist = checkdatabase();
        if (dbexist) {
            //System.out.println("Database exists");
            opendatabase(); 
        } else {
            System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
            createdatabase();
        }
    }

    public void createdatabase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbexist = checkdatabase();
        if(dbexist) {
            //System.out.println(" Database exists.");
        } else {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copydatabase();
            } catch(IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }   

    private boolean checkdatabase() {
        //SQLiteDatabase checkdb = null;
        boolean checkdb = false;
        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            File dbfile = new File(myPath);
            //checkdb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
            checkdb = dbfile.exists();
        } catch(SQLiteException e) {
            System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
        }
        return checkdb;
    }

    private void copydatabase() throws IOException {
        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myinput = mycontext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outfilename = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myoutput = new FileOutputStream("/data/data/(packagename)/databases   /(datbasename).sqlite");

        // transfer byte to inputfile to outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myinput.read(buffer))>0) {
            myoutput.write(buffer,0,length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myoutput.flush();
        myoutput.close();
        myinput.close();
    }

    public void opendatabase() throws SQLException {
        //Open the database
        String mypath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mypath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    public synchronized void close() {
        if(myDataBase != null) {
            myDataBase.close();
        }
        super.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Подскажите, а из какой библиотеки Context ? Вроде все стандартные библиотеки перебрал, ни в одном не было Context.getAssets()

Comment: @StriBog это контекст вашего приложения, если вы используете сторонние библиотеки для работы с базой, тогда вам нужно ДО инициализации базы проверить файл на доступность на диске. если файла нет то скопировать его из ваших ресурсов (assets) в папку приложения. для этого достаточно вынести 2 метода 'checkdatabase()' и 'copydatabase()'.

Comment: Добавил код в вопрос на основе вашего примера, в вашем примере один из параметров класса - Context context  , в моём же случаи если я создам конструктор и туда один из параметров Context, то он ведь не вызовется

Comment: В общем приложение падает при обращении к mycontext.getAssets(), т.к.  mycontext == null