# При переходе в новую активность приложение выдаёт ошибку

Tags: java, android-studio, sqlite

При переходе в новую активность приложение выдаёт ошибку:

> Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.chernovik/com.example.chernovik.UserActivity}:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: users (code
>   1): , while compiling: select * from users where _id=?

Ниже приведен код активности, при переходе в которую выскакивает ошибка

```
package com.example.chernovik;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class UserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText nameBox;
    Button delButton;
    Button saveButton;

    DataBaseHelper sqlHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Cursor userCursor;
    long userId=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.user);

        nameBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        delButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
        saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveButton);

        sqlHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
        db = sqlHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            userId = extras.getLong("id");
        }
        // если 0, то добавление
        if (userId > 0) {
            // получаем элемент по id из бд
            userCursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + DataBaseHelper.TABLE + " where " +
                    DataBaseHelper.COLUMN_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(userId)});
            userCursor.moveToFirst();
            nameBox.setText(userCursor.getString(1));
            userCursor.close();
        }
    }
    public void save(View view){
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(DataBaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME, nameBox.getText().toString());

        if (userId > 0) {
            db.update(DataBaseHelper.TABLE, cv, DataBaseHelper.COLUMN_ID + "=" + String.valueOf(userId), null);
        } else {
            db.insert(DataBaseHelper.TABLE, null, cv);
        }
        goHome();
    }
    public void delete(View view){
        db.delete(DataBaseHelper.TABLE, "_id = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(userId)});
        goHome();
    }
    private void goHome(){
        // закрываем подключение
        db.close();
        // переход к главной activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Так же приведу код активности, в которой находится база данных:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;




public class ActivityList extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView txtListView;
    Button b1;
    Button b2;
    Button b3;
    EditText eT;
    ListView listView;
    DataBaseHelper databaseHelper;
    SimpleCursorAdapter userAdapter;
    Cursor userCursor;
    SQLiteDatabase db_sort;
    long userId=0;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
        b1 = findViewById(R.id.b1);
        txtListView = findViewById(R.id.txtListView);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String outputString = intent.getStringExtra("name");
        txtListView.setText(outputString);
        databaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        listView=findViewById(R.id.List);
        eT=findViewById(R.id.eT);

        //создаём БД
       databaseHelper.create_db();
       listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserActivity.class);
               intent.putExtra("id", id);
               startActivity(intent);
           }

       });

    }
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
// открываем подключение
    db_sort = databaseHelper.open();
    //получаем данные из бд в виде курсора
    userCursor =  db_sort.rawQuery("select * from "+ DataBaseHelper.TABLE, null);

    // определяем, какие столбцы из курсора будут выводиться в ListView
    String[] headers = new String[]{DataBaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME};
    // создаем адаптер, передаем в него курсор
    userAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
            userCursor, headers, new int[]{android.R.id.text1}, 0);
    listView.setAdapter(userAdapter);



    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(DataBaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME, eT.getText().toString());
            db_sort.update(DataBaseHelper.TABLE, cv, DataBaseHelper.COLUMN_ID + "=" + String.valueOf(userId),  null);
            db_sort.insert(DataBaseHelper.TABLE, null, cv);
            userCursor =  db_sort.rawQuery("select * from "+ DataBaseHelper.TABLE, null);
            userAdapter.swapCursor(userCursor);
        }

    });
    b2 = findViewById(R.id.b2);
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            db_sort.delete(DataBaseHelper.TABLE, "_id = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(userId)});
        }
    });
    b3 = findViewById(R.id.b3);
    b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            try {
                databaseHelper.close();
                userCursor.close();
                finish();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    });
}

        }
```

Код базы данных:

```
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

//import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String DB_PATH; // полный путь к базе данных
    static String DB_NAME = "AESDataBase.db";
    private static final int SCHEMA = 1; // версия базы данных
    static final String TABLE = "users"; // название таблицы в бд
    // названия столбцов
    static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    private Context myContext;

    DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, SCHEMA);
        this.myContext=context;
        DB_PATH =context.getFilesDir().getPath()+DB_NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,  int newVersion) {
    }

    void create_db(){
        InputStream myInput;
        OutputStream myOutput;
        try {
            File file = new File(DB_PATH);
            if (!file.exists()) {
                this.getReadableDatabase();
                //получаем локальную бд как поток
                myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
                // Путь к новой бд
                String outFileName = DB_PATH;

                // Открываем пустую бд
                myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

                // побайтово копируем данные
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                myOutput.flush();
                myOutput.close();
                myInput.close();
            }
        }
        catch(IOException ex){
            Log.d("DatabaseHelper", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
     SQLiteDatabase open()throws SQLException {

        return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }
}
```

Лог самой ошибки:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.chernovik, PID: 22166
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.chernovik/com.example.chernovik.UserActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: users (code 1): , while compiling: select * from users where _id=?
    #################################################################
    Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
    Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
        (no such table: users (code 1): , while compiling: select * from users where _id=?)
    #################################################################
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2924)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2985)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1635)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: users (code 1): , while compiling: select * from users where _id=?
    #################################################################
    Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
    Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
        (no such table: users (code 1): , while compiling: select * from users where _id=?)
    #################################################################
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1008)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:573)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1628)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1567)
        at com.example.chernovik.UserActivity.onCreate(UserActivity.java:40)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6912)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2877)
            ... 9 more
```

таблица users задана в базе данных
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавили таблицу или изменили ее имя после первого запуска приложения?

Comment: @pavlofff нет, таблица оставалась прежней, без изменений

Comment: в вашей БД нет таблицы с именем users, так сказано в сообщении о ошибке.

Comment: @pavlofff а сейчас даже при переходе в активность ActivityList лог выдаёт ошибку:                             Unable to resume activity {com.example.chernovik/com.example.chernovik.ActivityList}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 1294): Could not open database
    #################################################################
    Error Code : 1294 (SQLITE_CANTOPEN_ENOENT)
    Caused By : Specified directory or database file does not exist.
     (unknown error (code 1294): Could not open database)

Comment: @pavlofff возможно, какая-нибудь ошибка с созданием или объявлением базы данных?

Comment: ну теперь говорит, что не только таблица отсутствует, но вся база данных тоже (точнее по указаному пути ее нет). Я вам рекомендую для копирования БД [использовать оттестированные библиотеки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/523666/177345), а не сомнительный код из сети. Не забудьте деинсталировать приложение с тестируеещего устройства перед тем, как изменять чт то в структуре БД.

Comment: @pavlofff выдаёт первоначальную ошибку

Comment: значит в копируемой базе нет таблицы users

Comment: @pavlofff добавил скрин того что таблица users присутствует в базе данных