# DB Как добавить готовую базу данных в приложение

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sqlite, sugarorm

Создаю приложение работающее в основном с базами данных,требуется чтобы после установки были некоторые заранее подготовленные. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: написать репозиторий для него. логично же

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/523666/177345