# Как заполнить таблицу SQLite при ее создании?

Tags: android, sql

Я использую SQLite в своем приложении на android, но только для хранения данных. Они не изменяются в процессе работы программы, только считываются из базы данных, я только заполняю таблицу при первом запуске программы. Но может есть какой-то способ получше задать изначальные значения для ячеек таблицы SQLite? Может это можно сделать через метод execSQL?
Текущая реализация:

```
 SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("Check",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean hasVisited = sp.getBoolean("hasVisited", false);

    if (!hasVisited) {
        //запись данных
        }
        SharedPreferences.Editor e = sp.edit();
        e.putBoolean("hasVisited", true);
        e.commit();
    }
```

Comment: Текущая реализация никакого отношения к SQLite не имеет. Shared preferences - это совершенно другой механизм Android SDK, заключается в сохранении строк в XML файл в виде ключ-значение

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/523666/177345

Comment: Я это хорошо понимаю, SharedPreferences используется только для определения, была ли программа запущена впервые или нет. Сами данные записываются в таблицу SQL

Comment: Тогда да, по идее вы можете прямо в классе-наследнике `SQLiteOpenHelper` в методе `onCreate` выполнить обычный запрос с заполнением созданных таблиц при помощи `SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(...)`

Comment: Я бы сказал, что ВЫ ДОЛЖНЫ в методе onCreate() класса-наследника  SQLiteOpenHelper заполнять свои таблицы (а не городить какой то костыль с преференсами) - этот метод выполняется только один раз, когда база данных еще не существует на устройстве (он ее, собственно и создает и наполняет данными)

Comment: Да, забыл добавить, что метод `onCreate` вызывается единожды при первом запуске приложения. Так же при повышении версии БД в `onUpgrade` просто дропайте все таблицы и вызывайте тот же `onCreate`