# Реализация БД в android-приложении

Tags: android, база-данных, firebase, mobile-development, android-sqlite

**Коротко о приложении:** приложение содержит локальную БД (SQLite) с рандомнымы фразами, которые выдает ежедневно в случайном порядке.

**Вопрос заключается в следующем:** как эти фразы занести в БД на этапе разработки программы?

Представим что у нас 500 фраз и если заносить их в методе onCreate () класса SQLiteOpenHelper то это 500 строк кода, который просто заносит фразы в БД.

Подобная реализация как на меня неоптимальная и будет тратить время пользователя при первом открытии программы. А представим что через год я хочу добавить еще 500 фраз это еще 500 строк кода.

Вариант вынести БД скажем в Firebase и тянуть фразы из него тоже не оптимален, так как программа должна работать в офлайн-режиме.

Comment: А как вы добавите кому то 500 фраз через год, если приложение должно работать оффлайн?

Comment: В play-market выпущу обновление, пользователь скачает и получит свои 500 новых фраз (банальное alter table)

Comment: По моему и в этом случае требуется онлайн. Ну тогда можно как строковый массив в ресурсах. В том же onCreate() находите его, а потом оттуда по случайному индексу достаете фразы.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/523666/177345